# How to use vue-i18n in Class Style Component(vue3)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-i18n, vue-class-components

I'm trying to migrate vue2 to vue3 which is "Class Style Component".

It is using vue-i18n. Can I use vue-i18n in Vue3?

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {

    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.5.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^10.0.0-rc.3",
```

I am facing the following error in browser console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Must be called at the top of a `setup` function
    at createCompileError (message-compiler.esm-browser.js:99:19)
    at createI18nError (vue-i18n.mjs:101:12)
    at useI18n (vue-i18n.mjs:2294:15)
    at TestXXXXXX.vue:20:9
```

It is saying "Must be called at the top of a `setup` function".
Is it possible to use "setup function" in Class Style Component?

The following is my code sample.

```
<script lang="ts">

import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

@Component({
  i18n: useI18n()
})
export default class TestXXXXXX extends Vue {
:
```

Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think vue3 class components are deprecated. https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/17#issuecomment-494242121 I suggest you use the composition api

Comment: Hi, vue-class-component is no longer maintained, and it is no longer recommended to use. You can see here the first warnong on the overview: [vue-class-component](https://class-component.vuejs.org/#overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite my comment, it's still possible to use [vue-i18n](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/) with [vue-class-component](https://class-component.vuejs.org/). In `Vue3` `useI18n` need to be use at the top of a setup function like said in your error message. `vue-class-component` export a setup function that you can use in different ways, we're going to use that. Here is how to do it.

First, you need to create your `app` and install `vue-i18n`:

In your `main.ts` or whatever is the entry of your app:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";

const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: "en",
  legacy: false,
  messages: { // add your messages here
    en: {
      common: {
        message: "Hello world!",
      },
    },
  },
});

createApp(App).use(i18n).mount("#app");
```

Now you can use `$t` and `useI18n` in your project, here is how to do it:

In your `App.vue` :

```
<template>
  <HelloWorld msg="common.message"/> <!-- The traduction key -->
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from 'vue-class-component';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

@Options({
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
})
export default class App extends Vue {}
</script>
```

And now in the component `HelloWorld.vue` here is the two ways to use it:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ $t(msg) }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ i18n.t('common.message') }}</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue, setup } from 'vue-class-component';
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

@Options({
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
})
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  msg!: string      

  i18n = setup(() => {
    return useI18n()
  })
}
</script>
```

I strongly not recommend you to use `vue-class-component`, but more to use [composition API](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html) with `Vue3` and `Typescript`.

However, hope it helps you :)